# Convert List<string> to byte array by lines using c#

Tags: c#

I want to convert a list of string to an array of byte to store it in a sql table, then download the file.

In the code below, I just focus in the conversion part.

```
List<string> Items = new List<string>();
Items.Add("1 - Test 1");
Items.Add("2 - Test 2");
Items.Add("3 - Test 3");

byte[] dataAsBytes = Items.SelectMany(s => System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s))
                          .ToArray();
```

Now, when I download that as a txt file the output is:

`1 - Test12 - Test 23 - Test 3`

How can I change my code in order to get each line of the `List<string>` in the downloaded file as the output below:

```
1 - Test 1
2 - Test 2
3 - Test 3
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could add a newline in the query. essentially adding a newline byte between each one.

```
byte[] dataAsBytes = Items.SelectMany(s =>
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s + Environment.NewLine)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 6):

You could concatenate new-line strings:

```
string fulltext = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Items);
byte[] dataAsBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fulltext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
byte[] dataAsBytes = Items.SelectMany(s => 
           System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s + Environment.NewLine)).ToArray();
```